Having issues with gtk/gnome applications not rendering at first on 24.04, Usually starts showing after cursor hovers
Initially this worked fine, but I noticed that some applications would not show text or buttons until I hovered over the components do they show up (guess forcing the elements to render).  I am not exactly sure the cause, I did notice this happened after an update I approved, however, not sure if it was caused by a removal of a library at the same time.  I did do a sudo apt autoremove.  I have included screenshots of what I am seeing.




Seems like this issue was because of a theme.  I was finally able to get back into the theme preference, and when I changed the theme to an older one I used before, I didn't see the rendering issue happening again.  Seems odd that a theme would cause this issue with rendering.
